# If $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is $F_\sigma$ and of first category, then there is some $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ with $D(f)=A$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Prove that if $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is $F_\sigma$ and of first category, then there is some $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ with $D(f)=A$

$D(f):=\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid \text{$f$ is discontinuous at x}\}$

What I know is, if $A$ is closed and nowhere dense, then the characteristic function $\chi_A$ satisfies $D(\chi_A)=A$.

So, does $A$ being $F_\sigma$ and of first category imply $A$ is closed and nowhere dense?

Moreover, if $A$ is just $F_\sigma$ does there exist a function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $D(f)=A$?

Answer (score 1):

> So, does $A$ being $F_\sigma$ and of first category imply $A$ is closed and nowhere dense?

No, the set $\mathbb Q$ of all rational numbers is an $F_\sigma$ set of the first category, but is neither closed nor is it nowhere dense.

> Moreover, if $A$ is just $F_\sigma$ does there exist a function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $D(f)=A$?

Yes, if $A\subset\mathbb R$, then $A$ is the set of points of discontinuity of some function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ if and only if $A$ is an $F_\sigma$ set; it doesn't matter if $A$ is a set of the first or the second category.

If $A$ is an $F_\sigma$ subset of $\mathbb R$, we may assume that $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ where each $A_n$ is closed and $A_n\subseteq A_{n+1}$. Define $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ as follows:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\ \ \ 0\ \text{ if }\ x\notin A\\\ \ 
\frac1n\ \text{ if }\ x\in A_n\setminus\bigcup_{m\lt n}A_m,\ x\text{ rational}\\-\frac1n\ \text{ if }\ x\in A_n\setminus\bigcup_{m\lt n}A_m, x\text{ irrational }\end{cases}$$
Then $D(f)=A$.

If the $F_\sigma$ set $A$ is a set of the first category, then each of the closed sets $A_n$ has empty interior, and so the construction of $f$ can be simplified slightly:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\ \ \ 0\ \text{ if }\ x\notin A\\\ \ 
\frac1n\ \text{ if }\ x\in A_n\setminus\bigcup_{m\lt n}A_m\end{cases}$$

Comment: For the first question, if my guess is wrong, how should I prove it? For the second question, how can I construct such function?

Comment: @bbw For the second question, see the addition to my answer. For the first question, I don't understand what it is you want to prove.

Comment: my first question is to prove : If $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is $F_\sigma$ and of first category, then there is a function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $D(f)=A$.

Comment: And your second question is to prove: If $A\subseteq\mathbb R$ is $F_\sigma$ (but not necessarily of first category), then there is a function $f$ on $\mathbb R$ such that $D(f)=A$? How does answering the second question not also answer the first question?

Comment: I know the second one is more general then the first one. But the answer to the second one requires a difficult construction of such $f$. So, I added one more condition: $A$ is of first category, to make the problem easier.

Comment: I'm more interested in the first one. Because I have proved if $A$ is closed and nowhere dense, then the characteristic function on $A$ is the function we want. Moreover, you answered my another post: if $A$ is $F_\sigma$ and of first category then $A$ is a countable union of closed nowhere dense sets. Can we use these facts to construct a $f$ such that $D(f)=A$?